# Find and replace using wildcard in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, replace, find, wildcard

How would one go about using replace in netbeans to modify a PHP script with lots of `$_POST[]`.

For better security it would be a good idea to replace all these `$_POST[]`
 with `sanitize($_POST[])` where sanitize is a function that sanitizes user input.

So I could use Replace and search for `$_POST['']` and replace with sanitize(`$_POST['']`).

But how do you keep the variable name within each `$_POST['']` while adding the closing parenthesis?

For example `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['action']` need to become `sanitize($_POST['name'])` and `santize($_POST['action'])` respectively.

Comment: you can try to replace `$_POST['` with `sanitize($_POST['` and `'] ` with `']) `. latter replace not all at once . Better is not to use global `$_POST['...']` **all over in your code**. put them initialized at the beginning of the script to an equivalent $variable. `if (isset()...){...}`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a PHP programmer or a Regex master but in my very limited test this seemed to work.

Select the project and then choose Edit -> Replace. Choose "Regular Expression" in the drop down list, set containing text to `\$_POST\[(.*)\]`and replace with to `sanitize(\$_POST[$1])`

[image: screenshot using regex]

Comment: Thanks. This worked great for 95% of the replacements needed. But there are about 250 that remain like this, where the first instance was captured and replaced but not the second. Any ideas?

(isset(sanitize($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']) == 'go')

Comment: Nevermind - got it. 
\$_POST\[(.*)\]  becomes  & \$_POST\[(.*)\]
and
sanitize(\$_POST[$1])  becomes  & sanitize(\$_POST[$1])
Thanks!